# How to do block style functions in swift

Tags: swift, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to implement FSLineChart in a Swift app and I got stuck here since I got a crash trying to set the labels for the class

```
chart.labelForIndex = ^(NSUInteger item) {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)item];
};

chart.labelForValue = ^(CGFloat value) {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", value];
};
```

I am trying to solve it like this

```
chart.labelForIndex = ({
    (item: UInt) -> String in
    "\(item)"
})
```

Framework it's here
https://github.com/ArthurGuibert/FSLineChart

Any help will be much welcome

Answer (score 1):

Here is the snippet I tried. It didn't crash.

```
let lineChart = FSLineChart(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
lineChart.labelForIndex = { index in "label + \(index)" }
```

Maybe the problem is not about setting closures? Can you post the crash log?